# Hard Disk space reduce after executing big query

Tags: sql-server-2008, hard-drive

After executing a big query (it is my mistake: I had only 1Gb of free hard disk space) SQL Server 2008 says there is no space for allocate some temporary tables...

The the 1Gb reduced to 33Mb on my harddisk...

- Where did SQL saved or stored those Mb?
- How do I recover the 1Gb free space ?

Comment: temporal tables or temporary tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TempDB` is the place where temp tables etc are stored. Did you try to restart your PC?

Comment: Yes I restarted first SQL Server, did not work, then restart Windows Xp, and did not work...

Comment: @Abdul Muqtadir: Is there a way to free space of the `TempDB` manually?

Comment: Did all the queries ran in a single transaction or you think that some could have been committed?

Comment: mmm, the queries ran inside a Stored procedure...and some actions were perfomed...

Comment: Find out the size of TempDB, try to move the TempDB to the other drive that has space.

Comment: If insertions could have performed, your actual database size must have increased thus increasing your hard disk space.

Comment: Is there other way?, I found http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/04/01/sql-server-tempdb-is-full-move-tempdb-from-one-drive-to-another-drive/ which describes what you say, but is there a way to free HD space?, Or free database space?

Comment: TempDB should have been cleared after you had restarted your PC.

Comment: database space could be freed if you can compromise to the delete the data if its not critical. Why not move the database to some other partition?

Comment: I am doing some tests, the database is only test, so If I delete that, that will give me the space I had?

Comment: Definitely if you delete the data, space will be recovered. What is the size of your database mdf and ldf files?

Comment: `tempdev 1 C:\SQL\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\tempdb.mdf PRIMARY 99520 KB Unlimited 10% data only
templog 2 C:\SQL\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\templog.ldf NULL 181184 KB Unlimited 10% log only`  after execute `USE TempDB
GO
EXEC sp_helpfile
GO`

Comment: IF I increment size of TempDB to a 500Mb Do I get a better performance??

Comment: Yeah definitely as far as I know, increasing the increase by rate also improves the performance.

Comment: But if your tempDB current size is sufficient for the queries you run, you will not notice any performance improvement as per my knowledge.

Comment: One last, I have noticed that after executing a big Stored Procedure, as time goes on, the HD space is being reduced like 1Gb every time I check the HD space, Why is this?

Comment: It might be because temp tables are created, being stored in tempDB etc. Queires while processing also occupies some space in tempDB